# Why can't I install Java's bin file on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, java

I have downloaded a version of *JDK* from the Oracle's site, the file is named `jdk-6u37-linux-i586.bin`.

To install it on Ubuntu I made it an executable and run it:

```
$ chmod +x jdk-6u37-linux-i586.bin
$ ./jdk-6u37-linux-i586.bin
```

I expected it to install JDK, but this is what I get:

```
./jdk-6u37-linux-i586.bin: line 1: html: No such file or directory
./jdk-6u37-linux-i586.bin: line 2: head: No such file or directory
./jdk-6u37-linux-i586.bin: line 3: title: No such file or directory
./jdk-6u37-linux-i586.bin: line 4: META: No such file or directory
./jdk-6u37-linux-i586.bin: line 5: link: No such file or directory
./jdk-6u37-linux-i586.bin: line 6: link: No such file or directory
./jdk-6u37-linux-i586.bin: line 7: $'\r': command not found
./jdk-6u37-linux-i586.bin: line 8: body: No such file or directory
./jdk-6u37-linux-i586.bin: line 9: div: No such file or directory
./jdk-6u37-linux-i586.bin: line 10: table: No such file or directory
./jdk-6u37-linux-i586.bin: line 11: tr: No such file or directory
./jdk-6u37-linux-i586.bin: line 12: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
./jdk-6u37-linux-i586.bin: line 12: `      <td rowspan="2" valign="middle" nowrap><a href="http://www.oracle.com"><img src="/errors/us/assets/oralogo-small.gif"'width="154" height="19" hspace="10" vspace="25" border="0" ></a></td>
```

with sudo, it is this:

```
./jdk-6u37-linux-i586.bin: 1: cannot open html: No such file
./jdk-6u37-linux-i586.bin: 2: cannot open head: No such file
./jdk-6u37-linux-i586.bin: 3: cannot open title: No such file
./jdk-6u37-linux-i586.bin: 3: Request: not found
./jdk-6u37-linux-i586.bin: 4: cannot open META: No such file
./jdk-6u37-linux-i586.bin: 5: cannot open link: No such file
./jdk-6u37-linux-i586.bin: 6: cannot open link: No such file
: not foundlinux-i586.bin: 7: 
./jdk-6u37-linux-i586.bin: 8: cannot open body: No such file
./jdk-6u37-linux-i586.bin: 9: cannot open div: No such file
./jdk-6u37-linux-i586.bin: 10: cannot open table: No such file
./jdk-6u37-linux-i586.bin: 11: cannot open tr: No such file
./jdk-6u37-linux-i586.bin: 12: Syntax error: redirection unexpected
```

Comment: You can just install JDK with `sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk`

Comment: I strictly want **jdk-6u37**.

Comment: are you sure that the bin isn't damaged?

Comment: are you using x86 platform?

Comment: @matan129 can't say because site doesn't provides checksums. I downloaded it with curl.

Comment: Can you provide a link of the download? I will check it on my local ubuntu.

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase6-419409.html#jdk-6u37-oth-JPR

Comment: That is a html file. Not a bin, probably a 404 page or similar.

Comment: @handuel html files are not that big.

Comment: @SantoshKumar Then how come all the errors name html tags, believe me those errors are bash stating that it can't execute html tags. How large is the file anyway.

Comment: html head title META body are all html tags, they would not be in a .bin file

Comment: If you really want proof then "mv jdk-6u37-linux-i586.bin test.html; firefox test.html" It will display as a website, as it is html.

Comment: @handuel Its 69 MB. Its really a binary file. When I open it in text editor I see first few lines have HTML code.

Comment: @SantoshKumar Odd... pretty sure using a browser will fix it.

Answer (score 3):

You have obviously attempted to download a broken link. What you are trying to execute is a html file, probably containing some error that would be displayed in a browser. Try downloading the .bin manually using your broswer, and then execute it in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I've downloaded the file from the link you have provided (without curl).
Just right click on it, go to `Properties > permissions` and check `Allow Executing File as program`.
Then go to terminal and just write the file path (including the file itself).

*I used the browser and not `curl` because with curl you can't accept the agreement on Oracle. This is probably why when you tried downloading this with curl it didn't work out.*

Worked for me.

Comment: That is the same as chmod +x the difference is, is that you used a browser to download it, not curl. As you have to accept a license agreement to download it, which you can't do with curl.

Comment: Indeed so, that's why I've used the browser :)

Comment: Lol, kind of misunderstood what you were trying to say. +1 for gui approach.

Comment: Ha thanks. Yeah, when i read this now it's unclear, I will edit my answer.

Comment: You all misunderstood me. I accepted the license from web browser, when download started cancelled the download and used that download link to download with curl.

Comment: @matan129 OK, tell me what are the first 10 lines of your .bin file?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, [here](http://pastebin.com/eY2awB2k).